# Total record count for Azure page pagination

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-table-storage

If we take the follow bit of code

```
var pages = TableClient.QueryAsync<Entity>(maxPerPage: 10).AsPages(continuationToken);

await foreach (var page in pages)
{
    return page;
}
```

This brings back all the records as pages and returns a single page and allows me to bring back the page the user has request for table pagination.

It wont allow me to add a count on the end as that wont bring back the total record count. Nor does it offer it in the azure pages object. Where I have looked online states that azure storage doesn't offer a total record count.

I dont want to go through each record and I dont want a second call to get all and count them either.

I was wondering if someone else had come across this issue and what their work around was?

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned there is no direct way that you can achieve count using the mentioned code. However, After reproducing from my end, I could able to retrieve the records count using the below piece of code.

```
var tableClient = new TableClient(new Uri("https://<StorageName>.table.core.windows.net/"),"<TableName>",new TableSharedKeyCredential("<StorageName>", "<AccessKey>"));

Pageable<TableEntity> totalRecords = tableClient.Query<TableEntity>();

Console.WriteLine($"There are {totalRecords.Count()} records.");
```

[image]

Comment: While this is helpful, its slightly pointless for my aim to make the backend handle pagination if I have a query that handles all the records to get the total count?

Comment: Its not the sole purpose but getting a total record is part of the pagination, so dealing with all the records isn't how I want to go about it. Seems as though its not a possibility to get a total count and not deal with all the data